# SQL 2005 - The column was specified multiple times

Tags: sql, database

I am getting the following error when trying to run this query in SQL 2005:

```
    SELECT tb.*
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM vCodesWithPEs INNER JOIN vDeriveAvailabilityFromPE
        ON vCodesWithPEs.PROD_PERM = vDeriveAvailabilityFromPE.PEID
        INNER JOIN PE_PDP ON vCodesWithPEs.PROD_PERM = PE_PDP.PEID
    ) AS tb;

Error: The column 'PEID' was specified multiple times for 'tb'.
```

I am new to SQL.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have the outer "select tb.*"?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The problem, as mentioned, is that you are selecting PEID from two tables, the solution is to specify which PEID do you want, for example

```
 SELECT tb.*
    FROM (
        SELECT tb1.PEID,tb2.col1,tb2.col2,tb3.col3 --, and so on
        FROM vCodesWithPEs as tb1 INNER JOIN vDeriveAvailabilityFromPE as tb2
        ON tb1.PROD_PERM = tb2.PEID 
        INNER JOIN PE_PDP tb3 ON tb1.PROD_PERM = tb3.PEID
    ) AS tb;
```

That aside, as Chris Lively cleverly points out in a comment the outer SELECT is totally superfluous. The following is totally equivalent to the first.

```
        SELECT tb1.PEID,tb2.col1,tb2.col2,tb3.col3 --, and so on
        FROM vCodesWithPEs as tb1 INNER JOIN vDeriveAvailabilityFromPE as tb2
        ON tb1.PROD_PERM = tb2.PEID 
        INNER JOIN PE_PDP tb3 ON tb1.PROD_PERM = tb3.PEID
```

or even

```
        SELECT * 
        FROM vCodesWithPEs as tb1 INNER JOIN vDeriveAvailabilityFromPE as tb2
        ON tb1.PROD_PERM = tb2.PEID 
        INNER JOIN PE_PDP tb3 ON tb1.PROD_PERM = tb3.PEID
```

but please **avoid using SELECT * whenever possible**. It may work while you are doing interactive queries to save typing, but in production code never use it.

Comment: Using select * is fine when you need all columns - even in production. It should be avoided when using joins or complex queries, not avoided **at all costs** regardless how simplistic the query is.

Comment: The problem with `SELECT *` is that tables evolve over time, and you might start bringing in lots more data than you expected, without realizing it. Also, you win nothing by using `SELECT *` instead of making the fields you are interested in explicit (except a few characters of typing.)

Comment: That's true, fair enough! :)

Comment: I agree, that `select *` should be avoided. Really nice advice.

Comment: this is proper solution and worked perfectly fine for me

Comment: Your answer's last query is same as the OP's query in question except for alias. How it works fine?

Comment: @Shad because the alias is exactly the problem, if you don't specify from what table the column you're selecting must come from, the server gets confused. I've always found that a bit silly especially when you are joining on that column. But that's the way things are.

Comment: I learned rather more than what I came here looking for. thank you sir.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you have the column *PEID* in both tables: *vDeriveAvailabilityFromPE* and *PE_PDP*.  The `SELECT` statement tries to select both, and gives an error about duplicate column name.

Comment: He does have it in both tables, not only looks like :)

Comment: You're right, Vinko. :-)
On a sidenote: Why my second table name doesn't get displayed in italics? (put it in *<text>*, but displays as *PE_PDP*) Preview is correct.

Comment: I don't know, issue for uservoice I think. I tried some of the usual tricks (adding spaces or reformatting) but it didn't work

Comment: @MicSim I guess the italic formatting does not like underscore in the name PE_PDP

Answer (score 4):

You're joining three tables, and looking at all columns in the output (*).

It looks like the tables have a common column name PEID, which you're going to have to alias as something else.

Solution: don't use * in the subquery, but explicitly select each column you wish to see, aliasing any column name that appears more than once.

Comment: Aliasing! That's what I needed to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using * to identify collecting all of the fields, rewrite your query to explicitly name the columns you want.  That way there will be no confusion.

Answer (score 1):

just give new alias name for the column that repeats,it worked for me.....

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to give more detail as to why your solution works. This will help OP and anyone that has the same problem in future