# SQL The column 'Id' was specified multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql 2005 - The column was specified multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058606/sql-2005-the-column-was-specified-multiple-times)

```
  SELECT TOP(20) * 
    FROM (SELECT * 
            FROM [3D_Benchmarks] 
            JOIN [3D_Slugs] ON [3D_Benchmarks].Id = [3D_Slugs].BenchmarkId) AS tb 
ORDER BY tb.FPS DESC;
```

I Get This Error:

> The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'tb'.

Comment: Obviously both `3D_Benchmarks` and `3D_Slugs` have the `id` column

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `select *` use `select table.columnname` or `tablename.*`.

Comment: but I have 20 columns, there must be a simpler  way, maybe assigning the columns with the Id with AS

Comment: `tablename.*` did it for me. I only needed to select from one table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
            FROM [3D_Benchmarks] 
            JOIN [3D_Slugs] ON [3D_Benchmarks].Id = [3D_Slugs].BenchmarkId) AS tb
```

3D_Benchmarks have id column,3D_Slugs have id column too.

for explame:[3D_Benchmarks].id as aid,3D_Slugs.id as bid