# The column 'TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID' was specified multiple times for 'YY'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written a query like this:

```
SELECT  
    YY.ACCOUNT_ID,
    YY.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID 
FROM
   (SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.TRANSACTION TE
    JOIN dbo.FUND_TRANSACTION FT
    ON TE.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID = FT.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID
    JOIN ACCOUNT A
    ON FT.ACCOUNT_ID = A.ACCOUNT_ID) AS YY
```

and getting error like this:

> The column 'TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID' was specified multiple times for 'YY'

Checked this : [SQL The column 'Id' was specified multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809288/sql-the-column-id-was-specified-multiple-times)

However, the issue is not resolved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: avoid `SELECT * FROM` - specify the column names that you want to select. From your query you will get 2 TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID one from `dbo.TRANSACTION` and another from `dbo.FUND_TRANSACTION`. So there goes the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with the `SELECT *`. Since the same column names can be repeat in the selection.

Explicitly mention the column names. The below query will work.

```
SELECT  YY.ACCOUNT_ID, YY.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID 
FROM (  SELECT FT.ACCOUNT_ID, FT.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID
        FROM dbo.[TRANSACTION] TE
        JOIN dbo.FUND_TRANSACTION FT ON TE.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID = FT.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID
        JOIN ACCOUNT A ON FT.ACCOUNT_ID = A.ACCOUNT_ID
     ) AS YY
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify from which table `TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID` you want to select. You have to specify column list with aliases / table names instead of `*`. Something like:

```
SELECT  
    YY.ACCOUNT_ID,
    YY.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID 
FROM
   (SELECT A.ACCOUNT_ID,
           TE.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID  
    FROM dbo.TRANSACTION TE
    JOIN dbo.FUND_TRANSACTION FT
    ON TE.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID = FT.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID
    JOIN ACCOUNT A
    ON FT.ACCOUNT_ID = A.ACCOUNT_ID) AS YY
```