# getting error 'Column specified multiple times' with union all sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, union-all

This is my query:

```
select * from (
    select Name, Address
    from table1
    UNION ALL
    select Name, Address
    from table2
) D
```

When executing this query getting error:

> The column 'Name' was specified multiple times for 'D'.

Comment: Use t1 and t2 as table aliases instead of just integers.

Comment: @jarlh this is just an example real table names are different

Comment: Your query should not be generating this error.  My guess is that the actual query has `*` in the subqueries.

Comment: You can find a complete answer here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058606/sql-2005-the-column-was-specified-multiple-times

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are right I am joining multiple tables in subquery, two tables having Name column and I am selecting all columns from one table and Name column from another

Comment: @ZzOussama I have lots of columns in these tables. I don't write all column names

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from (
      select t1.Name as t1_Name, t1_Address as t1_Address
          from table t1
             UNION ALL
      select t2.Name as t2_Name, t2_Address as t2_Address
          from table t2
) D
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Use alias names

```
select * from (
    select t1.Name, t1.Address
    from table1 as t1
    UNION ALL
    select t2.Name, t2.Address
    from table2 as t2
) D
```